# Application rejected due to not following iOS Data storage guidelines

Tags: iphone, ios

Iam using SQLite for storing around 3MB of data, the catch is that i cannot use iCloud oe Web Service for storing this data, because the application will be used by users, who will not be having access to net mostly.

Is there any other way to fix this problem? Need suggestions.

Comment: in your app you download any data form web server and store in sqlite?

Comment: be more specific why they rejected your app? What are that 3 MB of data? Describe how do you download the data and what you do with it.

Comment: http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2012/02/07/app-rejected-apple-due-downloading-images-documents-directory-what-do

Comment: Iam not downloading data from web server. 3MB of data im storing on device using Sqlite. The application has been done for one of my client, who is very specific that data should not be accessed OTA, becuase it will be used by people who will not have access to net or Wi Fi.

Comment: The main issue is where you keep the sqlite database file. Most likely you put it in app's Documents directory and that's forbidden according to new rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you download data from web server and store in SQLite or not need that data to user than you should save that data to temp dir not in documents dir because when we backup app by iCould than its get data  of document dir not temp dir 
and see also this : [not backup](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html)

Comment: Iam not downloading data from web server. 3MB of data im storing on device using Sqlite. The application has been done for one of my client, who is very specific that data should not be accessed OTA, becuase it will be used by people who will not have access to net or Wi Fi

Comment: This is not the solution I want. Storing in iCloud or accessing dat using web service, iam aware of this. But i need solution for storing large amount of data on device.

Comment: why not use not backup the data? for more information check my link which i in give in answer